# If $f(x) = x\log2,$ then find $f'(x)?$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have a function (natural log):
$$f(x) = x\log2$$
My textbook shows that the derivative of it is:
$$f'(x)=\frac{x}{2}$$
But My teacher told me that we should take the derivative of whatever behind the log as numerator, so the derivative of 2 os 0 and therefore:
$$f'(x)=\frac{0}{2}=0$$

The textbook is wrong or I am wrong?

While I am typing the question, I come across another question. What would be the derivative of:
$$f(x) = \log(x!)$$
$$f'(x)=?$$
None of the rules that I have learn from class can solve this (factorial), or am I just not learnt yet? Or I should use the same rule to take the derivative of $x!$ ?

Comment: Are you sure your textbook says $(x\log 2)' = \tfrac{x}{2}$...?

Comment: The question is incorrect. Are you sure it's $log2$ and not $log_2x$?

Comment: Your textbook sounds like complete rubbish. The derivative of $x\log 2$ is not that and the question (about derivative of a factorial ) it asks is nonsense.

Comment: This question is actually on a worksheet that my friend gave it to me. Thanks for all the answers !

Comment: the factorial question is not on the worksheet, it just came across in my mind

Comment: The derivative of $x\log2$ is $\log2$.  The derivative of $\dfrac{x^2}{4}$ is $\dfrac{x}{2}$.  The derivative of $\log_2 (x)$ is $\dfrac{1}{x \log_e(2)} =  \dfrac{\log_2(e)}{x }$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Factorial is defined only on natural numbers, so its domain is a discrete space. So, the derivative of the factorial cannot exist.

For the other question: Let $f(x) = x \log 2$. You know that $\log 2$ is just a number independent of $x$.

We know that $g(x) = 17x \implies g'(x)=17$

Similarly, $\ f(x) =( \log 2 )x \implies f'(x) = \log 2$

Comment: The function $n\mapsto n!$ defined on the natural numbers is obviously continuous. It can't be differentiated because its domain consists of isolated points.

Comment: @egreg Thank you, my mistake.. I'll correct it.

Answer (score 1):

f(x) = xlog2. log2 is a constant and hence derivative of f(x) = log2

For the second part,x! is defined for whole numbers.We do not find derivative of discrete function,because derivative is for contiunous functions

Answer (score 1):

nonononononono..... $log2$ is a number. so $f'(x)=(x log2)'=log2$ the best way to understand this is to use definition of deriviation.

for factorials, you can use $log(n!)=logn+log(n-1)+log(n-2)+...+log(1)$ for natural numbers. however, you should know what $1.2!$,$0.5!$,$\pi !$ means. i.e. you should define or understand some function like this. $$f(x)=x!$$ function called 'gamma function' has similar property.